# How to get small versions of hiragana and katakana Japanese characters rendered in quail?

Tags: quail, japanese

I'm running `GNU Emacs 27.2` under linux (xubuntu).

I'm using the `quail` package to render Japanese characters. When I enable Japanese mode, I can type romaji, and it properly converts what I type to hiragana. Then, when I follow that with `K`, it properly toggles to katakana and then back to hiragana when I type `K` again.

However, I also want to be able to type the small versions of the Japanese characters, both in hiragana and katakana, but have been unable to find any keystroke combinations which will cause the small versions of these characters to be output.

Is there a way to get the small versions of these Japanese characters to be rendered?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! I just stumbled upon the answer!

This post from `sci.lang.japanese` explains the answer:
https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/small-kana.html

I tried these character sequences under `quail`, and they work!

*Excelsior*! (Latin for "Onward and upward!")